# How to select the most recent time in mysql and return two values inside a function

Tags: php, function, datetime

I'm trying to return two results from a function, but only the first is showing in on my page.

Here is my function:

```
function latestcomment($forum_topics){
    $recent = mysql_query(" SELECT created, owner, topic_id
                            FROM forum_comments
                            WHERE topic_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($forum_topics['topic_id'])."'
                            ORDER BY created DESC 
                            LIMIT 1 ");
    $mostrecent = mysql_fetch_array($recent);

    $time = $mostrecent['created'];
    $name = $mostrecent['owner'];

    return $time;
    return $name;
```

}

Then I'm calling like this

```
<?php echo latestcomment($forum_topics); ?>
```

The table I'm calling from looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
| id    | body     | created             | owner    |
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
|     1 |    hello | 2019-12-01 15:50:27 | name1      | 
|     2 |    World | 2019-12-01 15:50:32 | name2      | 
|     3 |       Hi | 2019-12-01 15:51:43 | name3      | 
|     4 |     Over | 2019-12-01 10:20:30 | name4      | 
+-------+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

Also I'll like to pass the created(DATETIME) part of the returned function into something like this:

```
           <?php           
            $date = date_create($forum_topics['$time']) ;
            echo  date_format($date, 'F j, Y'); echo"<br>";
            echo  date_format($date, 'g:i A'); 
            ?>
```

using only one query?

How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_` functions since they are deprecated and will be removed. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: Use PDO.... But really?  `return` followed by `return`?

Answer (score 1):

Two returns. not going to work.

```
$output = array(
 'time' => $time,
 'name' => $name,
);

return $output;
```

Comment: +1 for creating the value before returning it, making the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work:

```
return $time;
return $name;
```

PHP will return the first value, and the line with the second return on it will never be executed. You need to do something like:

```
return ($time, $name);
```

Which will return both values, as an array. You'll need to amend the code you're using to deal with an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

After the first return is executed you leave the function, the second return is not even evaluated.  Return an object or an array.  Like:

```
return array('time' => $time, 'name' => $name);
```

Or maybe create a `comment` object.  Populate and return it.